# Should I use semicolons at the end of each PowerShell statement?

Tags: powershell, syntax

I've done a fair bit of programming in C#, but then I've also written a lot of T-SQL scripts. C# requires semicolons, and T-SQL and PowerShell they're optional. What do you do for PowerShell? Why? My gut feel is to include semicolons but I don't know why.

Comment: Are you talking about semicolons to end the line? this question is offtopic.

Comment: @Hex: Why would it be off topic? PowerShell is used to administer you machine, so why not...

Comment: @Hex Yes at the end of a line. Why is it off-topic?

Comment: Mark Allison, sorry it was my mistake because I misunderstood your question.
In linux powershell you do not need to add semicolons same as you dont need to add semicolons in MS DOS.

Comment: It's because there are squiggly brackets. Those and semicolons are like chocolate and peanut butter. They're inseparable. I blame Kernighan and Ritchie..

Comment: Best PowerShell Practice and Style: [**Avoid Using Semicolons (`;`) as Line Terminators**](https://poshcode.gitbook.io/powershell-practice-and-style/style-guide/code-layout-and-formatting#avoid-using-semicolons-as-line-terminators)
PowerShell will not complain about extra semicolons, but they are unnecessary, and can get in the way when code is being edited or copy-pasted. They also result in extra do-nothing edits in source control when someone finally decides to delete them.
They are also unnecessary when declaring hashtables if you are already putting each element on its own line.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Powershell primarily uses new lines as [statement seperators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(syntax)#Statements), but semicolons may be used for multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: Note that there is a practical difference between running each statement as its own command versus running multiple statements within a single command, as can be seen in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1383533/if-powershell-command-separator-is-semicolon-why-does-date-dir-make-dir).  My personal decision is to not use semi-colons so that my test results in an interactive session align with what my script will receive when it runs the commands.

Comment: The semicolon is unnecessary so it's better to leave it out.

Answer (score 26):

The key, no matter whether you choose to use semicolons or not, is to be consistent. If you are used to using them in C#, then continue to use them in PowerShell. If you don't want to use them, then don't use them. Pick a standard and stick with it for you and the people that will read and use your code. It will get ugly if you decide halfway through a project to start using them.